# JFileChooser and browsing networked machines

Tags: java, windows, linux, networking, jfilechooser

I am working on a little program that needs the ability to let users browse files and directories on networked machines as well as the local filesystem. I made the mistake of developing this component on a Windows machine... it worked fine there, but hid the fact that JFileChooser doesn't really "see" networked drives. On Windows, the "Network Neighborhood" shows up in JFileChooser. But apparently this is not typical, as networked drives are not Files.

When I added the chooser component to my program and tested it on a couple of Linux machines, I discovered what I should have already known... JFileChooser doesn't browse the network. So now I am at a crossroads, and could really use some advice. Is there a (Java) alternative I should be using? Or should I keep working with JFileChooser to coerce it into the behavior I need?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://vfsjfilechooser.sourceforge.net/) might help.

Comment: Thanks elec. I had seen VFSJFileChooser out there and considered it. After your suggestion I went ahead and gave it a shot. It's extremely versatile, but seems like overkill for what I'm trying to do. It seems like working w/ the FileView or the FileSystemView would be where one would look, but it's eluding me at present. In the meantime, I have managed to move forward by mounting the remote drive, but in the future something more like VFSJFileChooser will be needed. I appreciate your input. FWIW though, I am still looking for suggestions should anyone have any. Thanks again!