# JFileChooser - Not browsing through the 'Mounted Drives' in windows server 2008 machine

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, mount, jfilechooser, drive

I use JFileChooser in one of my java tool to browse file locations.

It has a problem in browsing into the mounted drives - We can just chose the mounted drive but cannot go to next level/open and browse into the mounted location.

But it works fine in windows server 2003 , but could not do the operation in windows server-2008.

Has any one experienced a similar issue ? Need your advice !

Answer (score 0):

I think another question has the answer for this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420657/jfilechooser-and-browsing-networked-machines), on how to use a [VFSJFileChooser](http://vfsjfilechooser.sourceforge.net/), which enables choosing files/folders from network drives and is based on  [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/)