# connect to an IP address true a file sharing program

Tags: java, ip-address, file-sharing

I have this file sharing program, where i can get mye files from a local location  JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("C://Users"), but i want to get files from a Server using an IP address. I have trying String hostname = "192.168.1.1"; but its not working. When i open the file chooser i get to my own folder. some tips?

```
public void download(String username) throws RemoteException, NullPointerException{                           
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("//" + hostname + "/C://");
        chooser.setFileView(new FileView() {
            @Override
            public Boolean isTraversable(File f) {
                return (f.isDirectory() && f.getName().equals("C://")); 
            }
        });
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
        } try {
            String fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
            File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            //String name = "//" + hostname + "/chatter";
            System.out.println(fileName);
            //ChatFront cf = (ChatFront) Naming.lookup(name);
            String ClientDirectory = getProperty + "/desktop/";
            byte[] filedata = cf.downloadFile(selectedFile);
            File file = new File(fileName);
            BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(ClientDirectory + file.getName()));
            output.write(filedata, 0, filedata.length);
            notifySelf(getUsername(), "You have now downloaded: " + file.getName() + " from the server");
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("FileServer exception: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Are you looking to somehow access _shared_ files across the network using your Java program?

Comment: Yes, i want a folder located on a PC that i can access from different computers using this 1 computers IP adress

Comment: I don't have a complete answer for you (hence the comment), but see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2420657/1101070) SO question and give that a try.

Comment: Its fine, i got it to work with the help from Wyzard:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `"//" + hostname + "/C://"` as the path for your `JFileChooser`.  That's not a valid path.  If you're trying to access files in a shared folder on a LAN, the path for that looks like `\\hostname\sharename`.

Even if no shared folders have been defined on the remote machine, may be an "administrative share" of the C: drive called `C$`, so you could use `\\hostname\C$`.  But you have to authenticate as a valid user on that system to have permission to access the share.  (I'm not sure how that'll work when you try to acccess the path from a Java program — Windows might pop up a login box for the remote system, or it might just fail.)